# Сортировка по времени и вывод на экран

Tags: php

Проблема следующего характера: есть таблица, в ней три колонки `id`, `name`, `time` (в формате `time()`), `station_id`.

*Нужно*: отсортировать все строки по дате времени и вывести на экран в следующем формате:

```
1-09
нейм 
нейм1
неймм999
2-09
нейм
нейм9999
```

Но у меня что-то не выходит. Выводит только 1 дату, хотя есть и другие. Код:

```
$q = DB::$dbs->query("SELECT `time`, group_concat(name) AS name FROM tables WHERE station_id = '100' order BY time DESC");
$q->execute();

while($list = $q->fetch())
{
    echo date('d-m-Y', $list['time']);
    $name= explode(',', $list['name'] );

    for ($count = 0; $count <= count($name)-1; $count++) {
        echo $name[$count].'<br />';
    }
}
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101152/discussion-on-question-by-a-------).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Использование агрегатных функций без группировки приводит к тому, что они работают по всем отобранным записям, возвращая один результат

```
SELECT `time`, group_concat(name) AS name 
   FROM tables 
   WHERE station_id = '100' 
   group by time
   order BY time DESC
```

Такой запрос соберет имена для каждого времени